# Outlook Web Access SMTP?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, web, smtp

How would I connect my school's `Outlook Web Access` to my iPhone. Would I use Microsoft Exchange or the SMTP server. And if I use SMTP / Exchange, how do I find the details for these. I have my school email's username & password, and I know the domain that the web access is hosted on, I just need to know how to connect it.

Comment: Contact school IT help desk.

Comment: Your school should be able to provide you this information.  You need to know the pop3 and smtp domain information.

Comment: Outlook Web Access is just another mail client that you are using, this time via your browser. I think you're referring to Office365 or similar account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [this article from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2480) as a starting point.  The server name would be the front-end server, or the website you use to log on your school's email using the web browser.

The domain would be the domain you would use when you log on to the in-campus school computers.  Chances are that it would be something as generic as STUDENT or ACADEMIC.  If you don't know, a quick call to the IT Help Desk would suffice, I mean, they would HAVE to know that.

Hopefully this gets you on a good path.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the modern Outlook Web Application, in the top right corner you should see a settings button. Select the button and click `Options` from the drop down menu.

[image: Options Menu, Outlook Web Application]

On the resulting screen in the left column toward the bottom you should see an option to see POP/IMAP settings.

[image: Options Page]

Clicking on the link should bring up a pop up will all the information you need. Note that **your information may differ.**

[image: Connection Settings]

Also, your username may involve your **complete email ID** (`user@school.edu`) rather than just the username.

For more details see [Phone and tablet setup reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/phone-and-tablet-setup-reference-HA102828259.aspx).